# I need to check the logs from current time to before 2 hours

Tags: unix

I need to  check the logs from current time to before 2 hours, can you please suggest me a command

Comment: "Unix" is a very broad term. Do you mean AIX? One of the BSD variants? Linux? macOS? HP/UX? Solaris? Something else? And *what* logs? Some systems produce multiple log files for different kind of events. And do you mean system logs or application logs? Which application if the latter? Besides being off-topic here on Stack Overflow, this question is also much to broad.

Comment: Also, if by _check the logs_ you mean extracting or processing rows in logfiles based on the timestamp, please post some rows from the logs to show the timestamp format and some work you have already done to solve the problem. And while you're at it, please edit that question to be more specific on what you actually require. It's pretty ambiguous as it is right now.

Answer (score 0):

For listing all logs in the current directory within last 2 hours (120 mins)

```
find . -mmin -120 -maxdepth 1
```

for logs within in last 1 day in the current directory.

```
find . -mtime -1  -maxdepth 1
```

You can use the find command to find all files that have been modified after a certain period of time.

Source : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10041/how-to-get-only-files-created-after-a-date-with-ls